# KeyListener works, but won't distinguish specific keys

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keycode

The KeyListener has been added to a JFrame called _window. Whenever a key is pressed, it prints the line I used to test it, but it won't print specific keys, like VK_A. Can anybody tell me why? My first thought was that it wasn't focusable, but KeyLis wouldn't print at all if that was the case, correct?

```
public class Gui implements Runnable {
public Gui() { }

private JFrame _window;

@Override
public void run() {
    _window = new JFrame("Window");
    ...
    _window.addKeyListener(new KeyLis());
}    

class KeyLis implements KeyListener{

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        System.out.println("A key has been typed!");

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            System.out.print("A! ");
        }    
    ...
}
```

In this code, "A! " won't print, but "A key has been typed!" will. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A snippet from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29) of `KeyEvent`:

```
public int getKeyCode()

Returns the integer keyCode associated with the key in this event.

Returns:
    the integer code for an actual key on the keyboard. (For KEY_TYPED events, the keyCode is VK_UNDEFINED.)
```

The important part in your case is

> For `KEY_TYPED` events, the keyCode is `VK_UNDEFINED`

---

Either use [`getKeyChar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar%28%29) if you want to stick with the `keyTyped` method or move the corresponding code into the `keyReleased` or `keyPressed` method.

*(Or, even better, use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html))*

Comment: I would attempt to use Key Bindings, but for this specific assignment, my professor wants a KeyListener. Not sure why...but thank you for that snippet, I had no idea. Never having used key input before, it's extremely helpful.